# Why computers can be modeled as sample and hold system

Tags: analog, computers, sampling, sample-and-hold

I was reading digital control system from book by Norman S.Nise and in book it is written that

"computers can be modeled as a sample and hold system "

Isn't computer is discrete time system and its output should be discrete  while sample and hold is a analog  system and its output is continuous ?

So how a discrete system (computer )can be replaced by a continuous system (sample +hold) ?

Or I'm missing something?

Comment: You are missing something.

Comment: What's the continuous equivalent of a discrete time system? It depends on the output filters. If you have no output filters you get sample-and-hold. Think about what a computer *does*. It calculates some value and outputs that value. Then that value is held at the output. A moment later it outputs a new value. Then that value is held at the output. And so on.

Answer (score 3):

With sampling you convert an infinite variable (time) to a discrete one.
Hold is just a helper for quantization of amplitude values as we haven't invented an converter which needs zero time.

I guess your book tries to emphasize that a computer "transfers" its results to the inputs, fetches other values, then the state is virtually "on hold" while the compute core (ALU) samples and processes the values. When ready, the next cycle starts. So a computer partitions its cycle in 2 or more phases, which is similar but not equal to a AD Converter...

That said we must keep in mind, modern CPU's are much more complex and much more parallel. So while a single CPU Core and its associated Input Registers might be in a "hold" state while computing a result e.g. a division which needs several clock cycles, the instruction fetchers, memory interfaces, DMA, other CPU Cores,... all might be pretty busy.

Answer (score 2):

There's no discrete signal physical circuits in the macroscopic scale that we can observe, they can occur only in atomic level. Every physical measurable quantity appears as continuous in macroscopic scale.

Voltages get changed gradually and the logic state is our interpretation of the voltage level or the timing of a pulse. We tend to make discrete classifications because our thinking and communication happens by using a language built of discrete symbols. But our spoken, heard and written texts are transferred with continuous signals where we are used to include and extract discrete information.

Of course we have built automatic circuits which do the interpretations of electric signals for us and launch operations which are based on predetermined rules for the wanted state transitions. That is what the computers are. Taking a sample of a a changing voltage at certain moment, measuring it and setting a voltage to somewhere according the measurement result and a inbuilt rule how to combine several results is what the logic circuits in computers do.